# Generate HMAC SHA256 in C

Tags: c, openssl, hmac

I am creating an HMAC digest in java application and want to verify it into the C program. I have a hardcoded secret key in hex format.

I'm getting Segmentation fault while trying to calculate HmacSHA256 in C. I couldn't figure out what I am messing up.

The java program

```
        byte[] decodedKey = hexStringToByteArray("d44d4435c5eea8791456f2e20d7e176a");
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES"); 
       
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");    //Creating a Mac object
            mac.init(key);        //Initializing the Mac object
            byte[] bytes = challenge.getBytes();   
            byte[] macResult = mac.doFinal(bytes);
            return macResult;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("Not valid algorithm"+ e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid key"+ e);
        }
```

C program

```
    const char* key = hexstr_to_char("d44d4435c5eea8791456f2e20d7e176a");
    unsigned char *result;
    unsigned int* resultlen;
    hmac_sha256(key, strlen(key),
                               challenge, strlen("d44d4435c5eea8791456f2e20d7e176a"),
                               result, resultlen);



unsigned char* hmac_sha256(const void *key, int keylen,
                           const unsigned char *data, int datalen,
                           unsigned char *result, unsigned int* resultlen)
{
    return HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, keylen, data, datalen, result, resultlen);
}

unsigned char* hexstr_to_char(const char* hexstr)
{
    size_t len = strlen(hexstr);
    if (len % 2 != 0)
        return NULL;
    size_t final_len = len / 2;
    unsigned char* chrs = (unsigned char*)malloc((final_len+1) * sizeof(*chrs));
    for (size_t i=0, j=0; j<final_len; i+=2, j++)
        chrs[j] = (hexstr[i] % 32 + 9) % 25 * 16 + (hexstr[i+1] % 32 + 9) % 25;
    chrs[final_len] = '\0';
    return chrs;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault and that is the minimum amount of info you should already know and should share here.

Comment: Hint: where do `result` and `resultlen` point?

Comment: You need to allocate a buffer for your results, not just pass in an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for HMAC() more carefully you'll see that there are a few ways to call the method to determine size of the output buffer, or to let it return a static array buffer.

You can pass NULL for the result and get the length with a first call, then allocate the result buffer and call again.

Or you can pass NULL for the result buffer, and it will return a static array buffer (which you don't own), however that is documented as not thread-safe.

The easiest way may be to rely on EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE to statically declare your buffer. You should also declare the length variable as int not int*, and pass its address with the & operation - this is very basic C.

Try this:

```
unsigned int resultlen = 0;
unsigned char resultbuf[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
hmac_sha256(key, strlen(key), challenge, strlen("d44d4435c5eea8791456f2e20d7e176a"),
                         resultbuf, &resultlen);
```

Documentation:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/HMAC.html

There are many C language tutorials out there.